# Late dispatch in Swift

Tags: c++, objective-c, swift

According to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38941323/14440572):

> **Late dispatch**
> The function is determined at compile time, but the actual implementation depends on the type of the object at runtime. Important for inheritance. The compiler will check if the the class or any of its parents have the function declared, but its up to the runtime to choose which implementation to use. The late binding can be implemented using virtual tables like in the case of C++.

As I know Static dispatch(compile time bind the methods and object- Swift concept) and dynamic dispatch(run time send messages to the object- Objective-C concept).

If i am wrong or missing some important points please tell me

I wonder what about the Late dispatch in terms of Swift and Objective-C. Is there a thing just for C++ ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can read more about dispatching in Swift here - https://www.rightpoint.com/rplabs/switch-method-dispatch-table. Later on the fact that Late Dispatch is in many ways similar to Table Dispatch, where we have a declaration at compile time, but when dispatching, we substitute the necessary implementation depending on the object that calls the method.